# To not see Interactive Markers from other hosts

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say multiple users share a single robot while they open `RViz` on their computers to interact with a single robot, particularly by `Interactive Markers`. This is easily done, but a problem is that everybody who connects to the robot sees on their RViz multiple Interactive Markers that are run by other people, making the view on RViz simply confusing with possibly many Markers, and also making the operations on RViz harder (e.g. seeing which Markers are yours, finding particular tf frames).

Is there any way where each person ONLY sees the Interactive Markers of their own in this situation?
Or alternatively, users can share a single set of Interactive Markers if that is easier.

Using Hydro onward.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201232/to-not-see-interactive-markers-from-other-hosts/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's an interesting use case. It could probably be addressed by modifying interactive marker server to use SingleSubscriberPublishers, where each 'client' gets its own state, even though they all subscribe to the same topic.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1